# Unable to redirect to the specific location on page in codeigniter using controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I want to redirect below-given link from another page to the page view called `"profile.php"`  called by `previewProfile()` method in a model where `"brdetails"` is a name of an anchor tag which is on the page. I want the page to be scrolled on the redirected page where anchor tag is mentioned.

### viewname.php [ Below given code call profile.php using previewProfile() method in model ]

```
<a href="<?php print base_url();?>Controller_Name/previewProfile/1/#brdetails" >
   Preview
</a>
```

### Profile.php

```
<a name="brdetails"></a>
```

Comment: Do this  <?php print base_url('Controller_Name/previewProfile/1/#brdetails');?>

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri Thank you.... but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

use route for everything..go to application->config->routes.php in there use like this

```
$route['View_Function'] = "controllerName/View_Function";//normal view 
$route['SaveFunction'] = " controllerName/SaveFunction"; 
$route['UpdateFunction'] = " controllerName/UpdateFunction"; 
$route['Function_Listing'] = "controllerName/Function_Listing";
//load list only $route['Function_Listing/(:num)'] ="controllerName/Function_Listing/$1";
//pagination 
$route['Edit_Function/(:num)'] = "controllerName/Edit_Function/$1"; 
$route['Delete_Function'] = "controllerName/Delete_Function";
```

---

and then in your view

```
<a href="<?php print base_url();?>Edit_Function/prifle_id" >Preview</a>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Controller_Name/previewProfile#brdetails" >
   Preview
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not scrolling down to specific id is, you didn't include any `id="brdetails"` in the `<a name="brdetails"></a>`.

In your `profile.php` change the `<a name="brdetails"></a>` to `<a id="brdetails"></a>`

Hope this will help.